# Programatically get heap info using jmx with java 5

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, jmx

I am aware of using jconsole to attach to a java process to get memory information.  Specifically I'm after getting information on the various memory pools programatically so I can tie it to a monitoring application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks mattk - I wound up doing basically this :-)

```
List memBeans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();           
for (Iterator i = memBeans.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    MemoryPoolMXBean mpool = (MemoryPoolMXBean)i.next();
    MemoryUsage usage = mpool.getUsage();

    String name = mpool.getName();      
    float init = usage.getInit()/1000;
    float used = usage.getUsed()/1000;
    float committed = usage.getCommitted()/1000;
    float max = usage.getMax()/1000;
    float pctUsed = (used / max)*100;
    float pctCommitted = (committed / max)*100;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html) and related classes.