# Find the heapsize in JRE

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I have linux system in which I have a JVM and it is used by 3 java process.

```
/home/codesrc>java -version
          java version "1.7.0_09"
          Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
          Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

So, I have 3 process running using the same JRE.
each of this process has its own memory defined at command line when instating like

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -cp $CLASSPATH <class name>
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -cp $CLASSPATH <class name>
java -Xms256m -Xmx705m -cp $CLASSPATH <class name>
```

The memory on the linux system is 4GB. I am trying to find the heap usage separately for each of these process. Since I have no JDK on the system I am unable to use jmap, jconsole or jstack.
I tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

but that does not give me process based and also the output for the above doesn't see right
Do any one have an idea on how to check the heap usage when only using JRE, something equivalent to

```
jmap -heap <PID>
```

Comment: You can use visualvm or jconsole to connect to the running process and see its heap size.

Comment: I tried to jmap  and jstack by installing JDK and i am getting the below error:

     Attaching to process ID 10431, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Type "nmethodBucket*", referenced in VMStructs::localHotSpotVMStructs in the remote VM, was not present in the remote VMStructs::localHotSpotVMTypes table (should have been caught in the debug build of that VM). Can not continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the current memory usage of your running process?  Have you tried the following?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

Comment: yes I did, "Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()" will give you the usage on whole at JRE level, I need at individual process level
some thing like jmap -heap <pid>

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose that I had been under the impression that each process runs in its own JVM with its own heap.  Is this not the case?

Comment: I don't think so, because all my java process are pointing to the same version of JRE and when I wrote a small command line java program to calculate heap which uses [ Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()] , so again my question goes back to the point how can we see the heap usage for individual java process. Lets consider your impression is right, then how would I find the heap usage for a single JAVA process when only JRE is available in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to [enable the JMX agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdenl) when you start the Java VM on your server and use a host with [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) available to connect.

Alternatively you can use a local app which uses JMX to retrieve the details ([see other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462677/programatically-get-heap-info-using-jmx-with-java-5)):

```
List memBeans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();           
for (Iterator i = memBeans.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    MemoryPoolMXBean mpool = (MemoryPoolMXBean)i.next();
    MemoryUsage usage = mpool.getUsage();

    String name = mpool.getName();      
    float init = usage.getInit()/1000;
    float used = usage.getUsed()/1000;
    float committed = usage.getCommitted()/1000;
    float max = usage.getMax()/1000;
    float pctUsed = (used / max)*100;
    float pctCommitted = (committed / max)*100;

}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that JMX agent and the connectors would consume memory as well. If your application is currently critical in memory resources and you open this, you can make your app throws an OOM =\